# Relay router, deprecate fetch on first render

Tags: relayjs, relay, react-router-relay, react-relay

I have met next issue.
In `my app` I use relay, custom network layer and relay-router

For plain `route` I declare query, that fetch some data:

```
const ViewerQuery = {
  viewer: Component => Relay.QL`
    query {
        viewer {
            ${Component.getFragment('viewer')}
        }
    }`
};
```

And in `component`, the `router` before assigned, I've got next relay container:

```
export default Relay.createContainer(App, {
  initialVariables: {
    isNoDataCached: false,
  },
  fragments: {
    viewer: () => Relay.QL`
        fragment on Viewer {
            appConfig @include(if: $isNoDataCached) {
                appData{
                    ${appData}
                }
            }
        }`
  }
});
```

By default it fetch `{query { viewer } }` because
**$isNoDataCached is false**.

And returns

> 500 error.

So, is there any way to stop data fetching if I doesn't need to fetch data?